# How to add a an attribute to existing datasource using Jboss CLI

Tags: jboss, command-line-interface

I need to add the below values to my existing data source through CLI commands in jboss EAP server

```
<connection-property name="auto Commit">false</connection-property>
<transaction-isolation>TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED</transaction-isolation>
```

I have tried to use below command but its says duplicate resource

Comment: Where is the "below command"?

Answer (score 0):

`TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED` is the attribute value for transaction isolation.

**transaction-isolation** : This element specifies the java.sql.Connection transaction isolation level to use. The constants defined in the Connection interface are the possible element content values and include:

1. TRANSACTION_READ_UNCOMMITTED
2. TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED
3. TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ
4. TRANSACTION_SERIALIZABLE
5. TRANSACTION_NONE

You can use the following command to add any of the above strategies:

```
/profile=full/subsystem=datasources/data-source=ExampleDS:add(transaction-isolation=<Strategy>)
```